# Log4r configurator throws exception instantiating EmailOutputter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, log4r

I'm setting up Log4r using an XML configuration file, and I can't get the EmailOutputter to work correctly. Here's my outputter tag:

```
<outputter type="EmailOutputter" name="exception_email" trunc="false" level="ERROR" buffsize="10">
        <formatter type="PatternFormatter" pattern="#{pattern}"/>
        <server>#{smtp_address}</server>
        <port>#{smtp_port}</port>
        <domain>#{smtp_domain}</domain>
        <from>logging@#{smtp_domain}</from>
        <to>exceptions@mydomain.com</to>
        <subject>Log Report</subject>
        <immediate_at>ERROR, FATAL</immediate_at>
      </outputter>
```

I've triple and quadruple checked that all the XML variables are being passed in correctly using the RubyMine step-through debugger. The exception message is:

Uncaught exception: Problem creating outputter: uninitialized constant Log4r::Configurator::EmailOutputter
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/log4r-1.1.10/lib/log4r/configurator.rb:87:in `block in decode_xml'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/element.rb:905:in`block in each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xpath.rb:67:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/xpath.rb:67:in`each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/element.rb:905:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/log4r-1.1.10/lib/log4r/configurator.rb:87:in`decode_xml'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/log4r-1.1.10/lib/log4r/configurator.rb:82:in `actual_load'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/log4r-1.1.10/lib/log4r/configurator.rb:56:in`load_xml_file'
    /root/src/upside/common/upside_logger.rb:16:in `initialize'
    /root/src/upside/common/logger_factory.rb:7:in`new'
    /root/src/upside/common/logger_factory.rb:7:in `new_logger'
    /root/src/upside/config/application.rb:30:in`block in '
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in`execute_hook'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in`each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:43:in`before_configuration'
    /root/src/upside/config/application.rb:29:in `<class:Application>'
    /root/src/upside/config/application.rb:15:in`'
    /root/src/upside/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in`require'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`tap'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    /root/src/upside/script/rails:6:in`require'
    /root/src/upside/script/rails:6:in `'

I've double checked the gem installation and the emailoutputter.rb is in the correct directory with the other outputters (which function correctly).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the log4r file `lib/log4r.rb` to be missing the line `require "log4r/outputter/emailoutputter"`. Adding this missing `require` to my Rails application in a `config/initializer` file allowed the EmailOutputter class available.

Comment: I found the same thing.